# Wait for download to finish before starting next download using php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, download

I'm downloading multiple files using `window.location.href` in an ajax call to a php file using `readfile()`. It works perfectly but all the files are downloading at once.

How do I wait for the previous file to finish downloading before starting the next?

I'll post code if absolutely necessary.

**EDIT - Here's the code:**

Basically I'm getting JSON parameters from a URL, then using those parameters to generate another URL, then sending that URL to my PHP code to download a file.

Javascript / ajax:

```
getEachData(vidList[vidListCount]);

function getEachData(vid){

$.ajax({
    type:
        "GET",
    url:
        "http://www.example.com?vid="+vid,
    dataType:
        "json",
    success:
        function(response){
            dlLink = response.dlLink;
            newFilename = "file_"+vidListCount;
            window.location.href = 'http://localhost/index.php?dlLink='+dlLink+'&newFilename='+newFilename;
        },
    complete:
        function(resp){
            vidListCount++;
            getEachData(vidList[vidListCount]);
        },
    error:
        function(){

        }
});
}
```

PHP:

```
$file_url = $_GET['dlLink'];
$file_name = $_GET['newFilename'];

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename='".$file_name."'");
readfile($file_url);
```

Comment: PHP can't do this, you can limit it via server, or try to set a limit tag when start downloading. when finish it, remove it.

Comment: @OlaEkdahl See code above ^

Comment: are you doing for loop? can you display the whole code including the loop?

Comment: @EmilReñaEnriquez There is no for loop, see my code edit above ^

Comment: ahh so you are using recursive. Hmm the page does reloads everytime it has success right?

Comment: @EmilReñaEnriquez The page itself doesn't reload, it just loads the .php file each time.

Comment: I want to add that this is becoming a bit of a problem in browsers with a maximum simultaneous download limit. I really need to solve this.